# lsof: what does number inside bracket of socket represent

Tags: linux, lsof

When I run lsof command, in name column, for sockets, some numbers are coming in bracket as shown below. What does it mean?

```
 command    pid        user      fd                 Name
 process    8197       root      29                 socket:[3050474]
```

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR**: A unique number associated with that socket

---

One of the defining rules of Unix is "[Everything is a file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file)". Because of that sockets are also represented by very special filesystem, usually referred as *sockfs*.

Files on traditional filesystems have *inode-numbers* -- unique numbers that allow to identify them:

```
$ ls -li /bin/bash 
7864369 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 656584 Oct 15  2014 /bin/bash
^^^^^^^
inode-number
```

Same applies to a *sockfs*, all sockets also have *inode-numbers*.

For special filesystems, that doesn't have actual filenaming schema, all files have generic names in form `fsname:[inode-number]` (see also: [linux+v3.19.1/fs/dcache.c#L2945](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.19.1/fs/dcache.c#L2945))

Comment: And if you wonder how that relates to a port number, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34032405/4178262