# lsof print numeric ports

Tags: unix, tcp, ports, lsof

How do you get `lsof` to produce numeric port information instead of attempting to resolve the port to service name?

For example, I want `TCP *:http (LISTEN)` to give me `TCP *:80 (LISTEN)` in-fact if at all possible I never want to see another service name in `lsof` print-out ever again.  So if there is a way to make numeric ports the default I would like to understand how to do that as well.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Run `lsof -P`.

And make sure the P goes before the i, if you combine the option with -i:

`lsof -Pi`

According to [`man lsof`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof), `-P` inhibits the conversion of port numbers to port names for network files.  Inhibiting the conversion may make lsof run a little faster.  It is also useful when port name lookup is not working properly."

Comment: From the man page:

 `-n`: inhibits the conversion of network numbers to host names for network files.

`-P`: inhibits the conversion of port numbers to port names for network files.

Answer (score 18):

Sometimes handy is:

```
lsof -Pi
```

When I tried `losf -iP` it gave me some trash, so make sure `P` goes first.

---

As a side note: `lsof -3.14` will provide the same trash, don't try this.

Comment: Weird that order matters, even on macOS' lsof.

Comment: Order does not matter. From man " -i [i]   selects the listing of files any of whose Internet address matches the address specified in i", so `-iP` means select Internet address matching P. Another thing is `lsof -P -i` works as `lsof -i -P`.

Comment: This works `lsof -i :4444 -P` for looking for processes listening to port 4444.  Nice side note on 3.14.  Give this a try: `alias lsof-3.14='lsof -Pi'` and then `lsof-3.14 :4444` :)